# cssで縦幅が決まっていないブロックの上下中央揃え

Tags: html, css

cssで縦幅の`px`指定をしない(中身に合わせた大きさになって欲しい)ブロックの上下中央揃えがうまくいきません。

下記は一応うまくいきますが、`html`や`body`に`100%`指定しなくてはならないのが気になります。

```
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
}

<div class="wrapper">
    こんにちは！
</div>
```

`100vh`を使う方法もありますが、各ページの上部にヘッダー(サイトアイコンなどが表示される)を置く場合に、画面が余っているのにスクロールバーが出てしまいます。

まとめるとこのような配置したいのですが可能でしょうか。
　・上部ヘッダーを抜かした部分の領域に対して
　・上下左右中央揃え
　・大きさの`px`指定無しのブロック

追記
ここに書いてあることがまさにピッタリだったんですが、記事の最後のコードだけ上下中央揃えになってくれました。(他はうまくいかない)
https://coliss.com/articles/build-websites/operation/css/css-centering-vertically-and-horizontally.html
もっとシンプルな方法があるといいのですが。

Comment: ヘッダーを含めた、現在問題としているコードを質問文へ追記していただけませんか？これらが現状でどのように実装されているかによって、回答内容が変化する可能性があります。

Comment: 指摘されたことで改めてコードと問題点をシンプルに明示しようと書いていたときに、問題点が「高さが決まっていないブロックの上下中央揃え」でなく「高さを画面いっぱいにする方法」であることに気付きました。そしてそうするには自分が書いたようにhtmlとbodyにheight:100%指定すること、有名サイトもこの指定を使っていることがわかりました。ありがとうございました。

Comment: ちなみに問題としていたコードは質問文のコードからhtml,body{height: 100%;}を除いたものです。